# Java 8 function to remove invalid whitespace from XML tags

Tags: java, xml, java-8, tags

I'm attempting to perform a data migration exercise, loading a series of XML files into a new format. The problem I've identified is that the XML from the legacy app has been generated with invalid tags, i.e. some of the tags contain whitespaces e.g.:

```
<Serial>0001</Serial>
<Document ID>12345</Document ID>
<Document Type>TypeA</Document Type>
```

Unfortunately there is no staff resource from the legacy system to correct the XML, so my only option is to fix it as I process the data.

Can anyone help with a neat way of using Java 8 to remove the whitespaces from the XML tags, making them valid to parse?

My original code to extract the XML was

```
final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
final JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(metadata);
return objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>()
```

Many thanks

Comment: It's worth seeing what utilities such as TagSoup or validator.nu do with it; they sometimes do a good job of repairing bad XML, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Java8-specific solution, but it does what you ask for.
Having your entire XML as a string, it uses pattern matching to identify the XML tags, and removes any space character inside them. Finally, `correctXmlString` has valid XML tags.

```
String wrongXmlString = <Document ID>12345</Document ID>;

// Regex for matching xml tags
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<[^>]+>").matcher(str);

// String builder for creating the correct XML.
StringBuffer xmlBuilder = new StringBuffer();

while (matcher.find()) 
{
  // for every string match (i.e., for each tag) 
  String tag = matcher.group();
  // remove any spaces and append the correct string
  matcher.appendReplacement(xmlBuilder, tag.replaceAll(" +", ""));
}

matcher.appendTail(xmlBuilder);

String correctXmlString = xmlBuilder.toString();
```